# I cancelled Rockruff from evolving because I wanted it to be a Dusk form, but it still hasn’t evolved

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I used rare candies, and it hasn’t worked. I also grinded in the grass, beating Pokémon.

It first evolved at level 24, and now at level 46, nothing has happened.

Comment: What Ability does your Rockruff have?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If the answer solved your problem please consider accepting it with the green tick

Comment: Do you have Pokémon Sun or Pokémon Moon? In Generation VII, Rockruff only evolves into Midday Form Lycanroc in Pokémon Sun and Ultra Sun (by levelling up during the day), and Midnight Form Lycanroc in Pokémon Moon and Ultra Moon (by levelling up at night).

Answer (score 4):

Only a Rockruff with [Own Tempo](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Own_Tempo_(Ability)) ability can evolve in Dusk Lycanroc. And it has to happen during evening.

But essentially your first problem is that you are playing Pokemon Sun/Moon, and Dusk Lycanroc is only present in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon.